# Missing ) after argument list in SFDC

Tags: javascript, ajax, button, salesforce

I'm receiving the following error

> "Missing ) after argument list"

when clicking on a custom button in SFDC. The aim of the button is to launch a specific case type in our Internal and Community environments.

Any help is appreciated!

```
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/28.0/connection.js")} 
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/28.0/apex.js")} 

if('{!$Site.Prefix}'!=''){ window.open('{!$Site.Prefix}/500/e?retURL=%2F500%2Fo&RecordType=0121b0000004IKZ,'_parent'); 
}else{window.open('500/e?retURL=%2F500%2Fo&RecordType=0121b0000004IKZ,'_parent');} 

var qr = sforce.connection.query("select Id from recordType where (name= 'Device Request') and sObjecttype = 'Case'");
```

Comment: Both of your `window.open()` calls need a closing quote before the comma.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
{
    !REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/28.0/connection.js")
} {
    !REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/28.0/apex.js")
}

if ('{!$Site.Prefix}' != '') {
    window.open('{!$Site.Prefix}/500/e?retURL=%2F500%2Fo&RecordType=0121b0000004IKZ','_parent'); 
}else{
    window.open('500 / e ? retURL = % 2 F500 % 2 Fo & RecordType = 0121 b0000004IKZ', '_parent');
}

var qr = sforce.connection.query("select Id from recordType where (name= 'Device Request') and sObjecttype = 'Case'");
```